# Best way to change font colour halfway through paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering what is the best way to change the font colour of some text that appears halfway through a paragraph.

For example, I have a paragraph of white text, but I want a couple of words in the middle of the paragraph to be orange so that they stand out, but then carry on with white text after that, what would be the best way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`<span>` will allow you to style text, but it adds no semantic content.

As you're emphasizing some text, it sounds like you'd be better served by wrapping the text in `<em></em>` and using CSS to change the color of the `<em>` element. For example:

#### CSS

```
.description {
  color: #fff;
}

.description em {
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

#### Markup

```
<p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit mollis varius. Etiam ornare placerat 
massa, <em>eget vulputate tellus fermentum.</em></p>
```

In fact, I'd go to great pains to avoid the `<span>` element, as it's completely meaningless to everything that doesn't render your style sheet (bots, screen readers, luddites who disable styles, parsers, etc.) or renders it in unexpected ways (personal style sheets). In many ways, it's no better than using the `<font>` element.

```css
.description {
  color: #000;
}

.description em {
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit mollis varius. Etiam ornare placerat 
massa, <em>eget vulputate tellus fermentum.</em></p>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this will cause the ".description em" to be orange in addition to being italicised. To have an <em> _just_ be orange, you will have to tell the browser not to make the <em> italics, by making the second block ".description em {color: #ffa500; font-style: normal; }" (whitespace removed by comment system :( )

Comment: @Hober: assuming a CSS reset hasn't been employed. As you've shown, default styles aren't an impediment to employing semantically-useful markup.

Answer (score 31):

```
<span style="color:orange;">orange text</span>
```

Is the only way I know of barring the font tag.

Comment: One should avoid hard coding the color inside the html itself.

Comment: eek. The font tag -- go wash your hands after typing that.

Comment: @jsbueno, agree, except when the color is tied with the semantics. For example, if the page informs the user that "In the map below, the **red** dots mark areas of interest", we may wish that the word "red" is colored red, regardless of any future restyling of the content.

Comment: I see this as the easiest approach with using a function. `"In the map below, the " + color_text("red", "red") + " dots mark areas of interest."`

Answer (score 8):

Nornally the tag  is used for that, with a change in style.

Like 
`<p>This is my text <span class="highlight"> and these words are different</span></p>`,

You set the css in the header (or rather, in a separate css file) to make your "highlight" text assume the color you wish.

(e.g.: 
with

```
<style type="text/css">
  .highlight {color: orange}

</style>
```

in the header. Avoid using the tag `<font />`  for that at all costs. :-)

Answer (score 2):

wrap a `<span>` around those words and style with the appropriate color

```
now is the time for <span style='color:orange'>all good men</span> to come to the
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply add the **font** tag inside the **p** tag.

CSS sheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
   p { font:15px Arial; color:white; }
</style>
```

and in HTML page:

```
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    <font color="red"> 
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris     nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    </font>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
```

It works for me.
But, in case you need modification, see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com)  for more usage :)

Comment: font tag is deprecated in html5, this is not the way it should be done the other answers are fine...